# XML Serialization with Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization, amazon-mws

**Introduction**

My goal is to convert a LIST into XML format. This list will consist of several "REPORT" nodes all with child elements.I am using XML Serialization to achieve this result.

**The resulting XML, will appear as this:**

```
<ReportInfo>
      <ReportId>898899473</ReportId>
      <ReportType>_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_</ReportType>
      <ReportRequestId>2278662938</ReportRequestId>
      <AvailableDate>2009-02-10T09:22:33+00:00</AvailableDate>
      <Acknowledged>false</Acknowledged>
    </ReportInfo>
<ReportInfo>
          <ReportId>894899473</ReportId>
          <ReportType>_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_</ReportType>
          <ReportRequestId>227162938</ReportRequestId>
          <AvailableDate>2009-02-10T09:22:33+00:00</AvailableDate>
          <Acknowledged>false</Acknowledged>
        </ReportInfo>
```

**ERROR:**

ERROR:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

reportXML.Report[index].ReportID = reportInfo.ReportId;

**CODE(1):**

```
/**********************************LOOP THROUGH LIST AND ADD TO XML****************************************************************************************/
                List<ReportInfo> reportInfoList = getReportListResult.ReportInfo;

                ReportListCatalog reportXML = new ReportListCatalog();

                int index = -1;
                foreach (ReportInfo reportInfo in reportInfoList)
                {

                    index++;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ReportInfo");
                    if (reportInfo.IsSetReportId())
                    {
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ReportId");
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.ReportId);
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportID = reportInfo.ReportId;
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportID = reportInfo.ReportId;

                    }
                    if (reportInfo.IsSetReportType())
                    {
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("                    ReportType");
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.ReportType);
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportType = reportInfo.ReportType;

                    }
                    if (reportInfo.IsSetReportRequestId())
                    {
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("                    ReportRequestId");
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.ReportRequestId);
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportRequestId = reportInfo.ReportRequestId;

                    }
                    if (reportInfo.IsSetAvailableDate())
                    {
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("                    AvailableDate");
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.AvailableDate);
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportDate = reportInfo.AvailableDate;

                    }
                    if (reportInfo.IsSetAcknowledged())
                    {
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("                    Acknowledged");
                         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.Acknowledged);
                         reportXML.Report[index].ReportAcknowledged = reportInfo.Acknowledged;
                    }

                }
                reportXML.SerializeToXML(reportXML);


            }
```

**My XML Class and Serialization Function:**

```
namespace AmazonWebService.Model
{
/***********************************************************************************/
    [XmlRoot("ReportListCatalog")]
    public class ReportListCatalog
    {
        [XmlArray("Report")]
        public amzReport[] Report;
        public class amzReport
        {
            [XmlArrayItem("ReportID")]
            public String ReportID
            { get; set; }

            [XmlArrayItem("ReportType")]
            public String ReportType
            { get; set; }

            [XmlArrayItem("ReportRequestId")]
            public String ReportRequestId
            { get; set; }

            [XmlArrayItem("AvailibleDate")]
            public System.DateTime ReportDate
            { get; set; }

            [XmlArrayItem("Acknowledged")]
            public Boolean ReportAcknowledged
            { get; set; }
        }

        /********************************************************************************/
        public  void SerializeToXML(ReportListCatalog amzReport)
        {
            String SaveDir = "\\" + System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath.ToString();
            String dt = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_dd_mm_hh_mm");
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<amzReport>));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(SaveDir + dt + ".xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, amzReport);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
        /********************************************************************************/


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you are doing this wrong - you should probably use XML serialization - see this page for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh.aspx

BUT in your code the error is that you create EMPTY array here:

```
public amzReport[] Report;
```

and  you never "expand" it. I would suggest you change that line to

```
public List<amzReport> Report;
```

and then change your main foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (ReportInfo reportInfo in reportInfoList)
{
    amzReport rpt = new amzReport();

    index++;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ReportInfo");
    if (reportInfo.IsSetReportId())
    {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("ReportId");
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" +  reportInfo.ReportId);
         rpt.ReportID = reportInfo.ReportId;
    }

    // all other code goes here...

    reportXML.Report.Add(rpt);
}
```